# outside vs inside __main__ variable definition in multiprocessing

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I have following code:

```
import multiprocessing
import time
import os

# WHEN SEMAPHORE IS DEFINED HERE THEN IT IT WORKS
semaphore = multiprocessing.Semaphore(1)

def producer(num, output):
  semaphore.acquire()
  time.sleep(1)
  element = "PROCESS: %d PID: %d PPID: %d" % (num, os.getpid(), os.getppid())
  print "WRITE -> " + element
  output.put(element)
  time.sleep(1)
  semaphore.release()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    """
    Reads elements as soon as they are are put inside queue
    """

    output    = multiprocessing.Manager().Queue()
    pool      = multiprocessing.Pool(4)
    lst       = range(40)

    # WHEN SEMAPHORE IS DEFINED HERE THEN IT DOES NOT WORKS
    # semaphore = multiprocessing.Semaphore(1)

    for i in lst:
        pool.apply_async(producer, (i, output))
        # print "%d Do not wait!" % i
        # res.get()

    counter = 0
    while True:
      try:
        print "READ  <- " + output.get_nowait()
        counter += 1
        if (counter == len(lst)):
          print "Break"
          break
      except:
        print "READ  <- NOTHING IN BUFFER"  
        pass
      time.sleep(1)
```

This code is working as expected and it prints:

```
READ  <- NOTHING IN BUFFER
WRITE -> PROCESS: 0 PID: 15803 PPID: 15798
READ  <- NOTHING IN BUFFER
READ  <- PROCESS: 0 PID: 15803 PPID: 15798
READ  <- NOTHING IN BUFFER
WRITE -> PROCESS: 1 PID: 15806 PPID: 15798
READ  <- PROCESS: 1 PID: 15806 PPID: 15798
...
```

Then I have this version which is not working (It is basically the same as first one except the definition of semaphore is in another place):

```
import multiprocessing
import time
import os

# WHEN SEMAPHORE IS DEFINED HERE THEN IT IT WORKS
# semaphore = multiprocessing.Semaphore(1)

def producer(num, output):
  print hex(id(semaphore))
  semaphore.acquire()
  time.sleep(1)
  element = "PROCESS: %d PID: %d PPID: %d" % (num, os.getpid(), os.getppid())
  print "WRITE -> " + element
  output.put(element)
  time.sleep(1)
  semaphore.release()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    """
    Reads elements as soon as they are are put inside queue
    """

    output    = multiprocessing.Manager().Queue()
    pool      = multiprocessing.Pool(4)
    lst       = range(40)

    # WHEN SEMAPHORE IS DEFINED HERE THEN IT DOES NOT WORKS
    semaphore = multiprocessing.Semaphore(1)

    for i in lst:
        pool.apply_async(producer, (i, output))
        # print "%d Do not wait!" % i
        # res.get()

    counter = 0
    while True:
      try:
        print "READ  <- " + output.get_nowait()
        counter += 1
        if (counter == len(lst)):
          print "Break"
          break
      except:
        print "READ  <- NOTHING IN BUFFER"  
        pass
      time.sleep(1)
```

This version prints:

```
READ  <- NOTHING IN BUFFER
READ  <- NOTHING IN BUFFER
READ  <- NOTHING IN BUFFER
READ  <- NOTHING IN BUFFER
READ  <- NOTHING IN BUFFER
READ  <- NOTHING IN BUFFER
READ  <- NOTHING IN BUFFER
...
```

It seems like if `producer` never writes anything to Queue. I've read somewhere that `apply_sync` does not print error messages. So I've changed `pool.apply_async(producer, (i, output))` to `pool.apply(producer, (i, output))` in second code, to see what is going on. It seems that `semaphore` is not defined, here is the output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "glob_var_wrong.py", line 31, in <module>
    pool.apply(producer, (i, output))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 244, in apply
    return self.apply_async(func, args, kwds).get()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 567, in get
    raise self._value
NameError: global name 'semaphore' is not defined
```

However following code runs correctly and print 10 (value defined inside `__main__`):

```
global_var = 20

def print_global_var():
    print global_var

if __name__ == '__main__':
    global_var = 10
    print_global_var()
```

It seems that in this code global variable can be defined inside `__main__` while in previous codes it is not possible. First I was assuming that variables defined inside `__main__` are not shared between processes but it only affects `semaphore` and not `output`, `pool`, `lst`. Why is this happening?

Comment: It's nothing to do with `__main__`. You have to define semaphore _before_ you create the pools.  Your code will work if you just move the line `semaphore = ...` up before creating the pools.

Comment: You mean before `multiprocessing.Pool(4)` ? How is this related?

Comment: @mehtunguh thank you this did the trick. Can you please post your comment as answer and explain the background details (I still do not understand why this worked) so I can accept it. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create a new process using `Multiprocessing.Process` (used underneath the hood by `Pool`, it copies the local scope, pickles it, and sends it to a new process to evaluate.

Because you did not define the variable `semaphore` before calling `Pool(4)`, the variable is undefined (in those OTHER processes where the code gets evaluated) and the function `producer` will throw an exception.

To see this, change the definition

```
def producer(num, output):
    print hex(id(semaphore))
    try:
        semaphore.acquire()
    except Exception as e:
        print e
    time.sleep(1)
    element = "PROCESS: %d PID: %d PPID: %d" % (num, os.getpid(), os.getppid())
    print "WRITE -> " + element
    output.put(element)
    time.sleep(1)
    semaphore.release()
```

and now your failing code will print out a bunch (40) of errors that looks like

```
global name 'semaphore' is not defined
```

This is why semaphore has to be defined BEFORE calling `Pool`

Answer (score 0):

It is because you execute the code on Windows.
You will get the expected results on Linux.

That's the difference between fork and spawn.

Comment: I don't see how this is relevant.